# How to arrange divs in a circle pattern in wordpress using php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In Wordpress, i want to arrange my posts in a circle, for now i will just work with divs. I hvae formulas for calculating the coordinates to the divs. I need to make the divs, and at the same time give them their coordinates. How do i do this? I know it is possible with javascript and JQuery, but i would really prefer, if i could do it with php, since my subject of study is php.

the line i am really interested in is this:

```
echo "<div class=\"circle\" id=\"<?php $i ?>\" style=\"position: fixed; background-color: red; left: <?php $Xcirclecoordinate?>; top: <?php $Ycirclecoordinate?>;\"";
```

[My wordpress site](http://www.nikolajlicht.com/wordpress/)

```
<?php 
$args = array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0);
$categories = get_categories($args);
$numcats = count($categories);
echo 'numcats= '.$numcats.'<br>';

$radius = 200;
#radius of the circle i want the divs placed in.
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
#The total number of posts
echo 'count_post= '.$count_posts->publish.'<br>';
#The number of posts published
$circlecenter = array('960','540');
#The center of the screen
echo 'Circlecenter= '.$circlecenter[0].' , '.$circlecenter[1].'<br>';

for ($i=0; $i < $count_posts->publish ; $i++) {
#Looping through the number of posts

$Xcirclecoordinate = $radius*cos((2*M_PI*$i)/$count_posts->publish)+$circlecenter[0];
#Calculating X coordinate
$Ycirclecoordinate = $radius*sin((2*M_PI*$i)/$count_posts->publish)+$circlecenter[1];
#Calculating Y coordinate

echo "<div class=\"circle\" id=\"<?php $i ?>\" style=\"
position: fixed; 
background-color: red;
left: <?php $Xcirclecoordinate?>; 
top: <?php $Ycirclecoordinate?>;\"";
#Trying to place the divs.
}
?>
```

Comment: Javascript...Do it with JS.

Comment: I know it is possible with javascript, but my teacher want me to do it with php. is this not possible?

Comment: Well, you could have that JavaScript code as a reference and try to code it with PHP.

Comment: True, but i am certain that the formula is correct. mostly i am in doubt if this is correct: echo "<div class=\"circle\" id=\"<?php $i ?>\" style=\"position: fixed; background-color: red; left: <?php $Xcirclecoordinate?>; top: <?php $Ycirclecoordinate?>;\"";